# python: записать в список с заданным шагом одно значение

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, производительность

требуется в список `arr` записать значение `value` с позиции `start` с шагом `step`

подскажите, как это можно сделать максимально производительно

я использую такой способ:

```
arr[start::step] = [value] * (len(arr) - start - 1)
```

но есть ли более производительный способ?

Comment: Вообще надо бы приводить параметры данных - что за массив: какого типа, какого размера, пример данных привести и всё такое )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для массивов достаточно большого размера `Numpy` вроде неплохо ускоряет.

Простой `Python`:

```py
arr = list(range(10000))

start = 10
step = 5
value = 42

%timeit arr[start::step] = [value] * ((len(arr) - start - 1 + step)//step)

# 16.6 µs ± 1.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Для `Numpy` размножать значение не нужно:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(10000)

start = 10
step = 5
value = 42

%timeit arr[start::step] = value

# 2.87 µs ± 580 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```